# Symfony3 - Left Join does not work properly

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Trying to solve this problem with Join in Symfony3.

Somehow the resultset has mixed up values, i.e

```
ID Exploit Author
ID Author Author
```

Please see the attached screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

OpenX should have Author Metasploit and the second row shouldn't be there.

Have this code in the controller:

```
 public function indexAction()
    {
        $exploits = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository('AppBundle:Exploit')->createQueryBuilder('e')
             ->add('select', 'a,e')
             ->add('from', 'AppBundle:Exploit e')
             ->leftJoin('AppBundle:Author', 'a')
             ->where('e.author = a.id')
             ->getQuery()
             ->getResult();

        return $this->render('exploit/index.html.twig', array(
            'exploits' => $exploits
        ));
    }
```

This view:

```
 <tbody>
            {% for exploit in exploits %}
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">{{ exploit.id }}</th>
                <td>{{ exploit.name }}</td>

                <td> {{ exploit.author }} </td>

                <td>
                    <a href="/details/{{ exploit.id }}" class="btn btn-success">View</a>
                    <a href="/edit/{{ exploit.id }}" class="btn btn-default">Edit</a>
                    <a href="/delete/{{ exploit.id }}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
```

And these Entities:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Author
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="author", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="author_name_id_idx", columns={"id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Author
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var \Exploit
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Exploit")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="author")
     * })
     */
    private $id;



    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Author
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getAuthor()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Author
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="author", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="author_name_id_idx", columns={"id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Author
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var \Exploit
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Exploit")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="author")
     * })
     */
    private $id;


}

<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Category
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="category", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="category_name_id_idx", columns={"id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var \Exploit
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Exploit")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="category")
     * })
     */
    private $id;



    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Category
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="category", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="category_name_id_idx", columns={"id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var \Exploit
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Exploit")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="category")
     * })
     */
    private $id;


}

<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Exploit
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="exploit", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="exploit_category_idx", columns={"category"}), @ORM\Index(name="exploit_type_idx", columns={"type"}), @ORM\Index(name="exploit_author_idx", columns={"author"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Exploit
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="bigint", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="edb_id", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
     */
    private $edbId;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="author", type="bigint", nullable=false)
     */
    private $author;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="category", type="bigint", nullable=false)
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="version", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $version;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="bigint", nullable=false)
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text", nullable=false)
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="dork", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $dork;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="software_link", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $softwareLink;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="tested_on", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $testedOn;



    /**
     * Set edbId
     *
     * @param integer $edbId
     *
     * @return Exploit
     */
    public function setEdbId($edbId)
    {
        $this->edbId = $edbId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get edbId
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getEdbId()
    {
        return $this->edbId;
    }

    /**
     * Set date
     *
     * @param \DateTime $date
     *
     * @return Exploit
     */
    public function setDate($date)
    {
        $this->date = $date;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get date
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDate()
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    /**
     * Set author
     *
     * @param integer $author
     *
     * @return Exploit
     */
    public function setAuthor($author)
    {
        $this->author = $author;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get author
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getAuthor()
    {
        return $this->author;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Exploit
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set category
     *
     * @param integer $category
     *
     * @return Exploit
     */
    public function setCategory($category)
    {
        $this->category = $category;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get category
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    /**
     * Set version
     *
     * @param string $version
     *
     * @return Exploit
     */
    public function setVersion($version)
    {
        $this->version = $version;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get version
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getVersion()
    {
        return $this->version;
    }

    /**
     * Set type
     *
     * @param integer $type
     *
     * @return Exploit
     */
    public function setType($type)
    {
        $this->type = $type;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get type
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getType()
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    /**
     * Set content
     *
     * @param string $content
     *
     * @return Exploit
     */
    public function setContent($content)
    {
        $this->content = $content;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get content
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getContent()
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    /**
     * Set dork
     *
     * @param string $dork
     *
     * @return Exploit
     */
    public function setDork($dork)
    {
        $this->dork = $dork;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dork
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDork()
    {
        return $this->dork;
    }

    /**
     * Set softwareLink
     *
     * @param string $softwareLink
     *
     * @return Exploit
     */
    public function setSoftwareLink($softwareLink)
    {
        $this->softwareLink = $softwareLink;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get softwareLink
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSoftwareLink()
    {
        return $this->softwareLink;
    }

    /**
     * Set testedOn
     *
     * @param string $testedOn
     *
     * @return Exploit
     */
    public function setTestedOn($testedOn)
    {
        $this->testedOn = $testedOn;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get testedOn
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTestedOn()
    {
        return $this->testedOn;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Exploit
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="exploit", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="exploit_category_idx", columns={"category"}), @ORM\Index(name="exploit_type_idx", columns={"type"}), @ORM\Index(name="exploit_author_idx", columns={"author"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Exploit
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="bigint", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="edb_id", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
     */
    private $edbId;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="author", type="bigint", nullable=false)
     */
    private $author;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="category", type="bigint", nullable=false)
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="version", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $version;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="bigint", nullable=false)
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text", nullable=false)
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="dork", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $dork;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="software_link", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $softwareLink;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="tested_on", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $testedOn;


}

<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Type
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="type", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="type_name_id_idx", columns={"id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Type
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var \Exploit
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Exploit")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="type")
     * })
     */
    private $id;



    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Type
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Type
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="type", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="type_name_id_idx", columns={"id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Type
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var \Exploit
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Exploit")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="type")
     * })
     */
    private $id;


}
```

Anybody know how to correct my join query ? Or why it behaves like this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
->leftJoin('AppBundle:Author', 'a', "WITH", "e.author = a.id")
```

Instead of this:

```
->leftJoin('AppBundle:Author', 'a')
             ->where('e.author = a.id')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 public function indexAction()
{
    $exploits = $this->getDoctrine()
         ->getRepository('AppBundle:Exploit')->createQueryBuilder('e')
         ->leftjoin('e.author','a')
         ->addSelect('a')
         ->getQuery()
         ->getResult();

    return $this->render('exploit/index.html.twig', array(
        'exploits' => $exploits
    ));
}
```

and in the view

```
<tbody>
            {% for exploit in exploits %}
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">{{ exploit.id }}</th>
                <td>{{ exploit.name }}</td>

                <td> {{ exploit.author.name }} </td>

                <td>
                    <a href="/details/{{ exploit.id }}" class="btn btn-success">View</a>
                    <a href="/edit/{{ exploit.id }}" class="btn btn-default">Edit</a>
                    <a href="/delete/{{ exploit.id }}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get this error: [2/2] QueryException: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 63 near 'a': Error: Class AppBundle\Entity\Exploit has no association named author

Comment: Well its because you have unidirectional OneToOne relation from author to exploit. if possible move the relation definition to exploit->author field or make the relation bidirectional (better to avoid bidirectional relations if possible)

Comment: Thanks! You seem to be knowledgeable in this area, maybe you can see at my other, related question. I have reworked my Entities, please see Update 3: in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46764888/symfony3-showing-one-to-many-relations-in-a-view .... but somehow it still does not work

Comment: Certainly. Please accept the answer if the solution worked for you.

Comment: Didnt work ... maybe you can test it on your system and export it later for me. Thanks!

Comment: Deleted the changes. I tried so many versions ... would really appreciate if somebody will get this to work and I can see a working version. This Symfony seems very complicated ....

Comment: OK Got it working. Please see:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46774151/symfony3-entities-dont-work-with-relations-database-with-indexes-and-constra/