# Symfony3 - Entities don't work with relations (database with indexes and constraints)

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Starring for this for several hours now, maybe I missed something obvious.

Have this database structure (with indexes, and constraints)

```
CREATE TABLE `exploit` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `edb_id` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime not null,
  `author` bigint(20) not null ,
  `name` varchar(255) not null,
  `category` bigint(20) not null,
  `version` varchar(255) not null,
  `type` bigint(20) not null,
  `content` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `dork` varchar(255) null,
  `software_link` varchar(255) null,
  `tested_on` varchar(255) null,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `exploit_category_idx` (`category`),
  KEY `exploit_type_idx` (`type`),
  KEY `exploit_author_idx` (`author`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `category` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `category_name_id_idx` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `category_name_id` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `exploit` (`category`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `type` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `type_name_id_idx` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `type_name_id` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `exploit` (`type`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `author` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `author_name_id_idx` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `author_name_id` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `exploit` (`author`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Created these entities:

```
::::::::::::::
Author.php
::::::::::::::
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use AppBundle\Entity\Exploit;

/**
 * Author
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="author", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="author_name_id_idx", columns={"id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Author
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", author="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;


/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Exploit", mappedBy="author", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="exploits", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $exploits;

/**
 * Author constructor.
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->exploits = new ArrayCollection();
}

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Author
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function __toString() 
    {
        return $this->name;
    }


/**
 * @param Exploits $exploit
 *
 * @return Author
 */
public function addExploit($exploit)
{
        $this->exploits->add($exploit);

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @param Collection $exploits
 *
 * @return Author
 */
public function setExploits(Collection $exploits)
{
    $this->exploits->clear();

    foreach ($exploits as $exploit) {
        $exploit->add($this);
    }

    $this->exploits = $exploits;

    return $this;
}
}
::::::::::::::
Category.php
::::::::::::::
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use AppBundle\Entity\Exploit;

/**
 * Category
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="category", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="category_name_id_idx", columns={"id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Category
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", category="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;


/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Exploit", mappedBy="category", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="exploits", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $exploits;

/**
 * Author constructor.
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->exploits = new ArrayCollection();
}

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Author
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function __toString() 
    {
        return $this->name;
    }


/**
 * @param Exploits $exploit
 *
 * @return Author
 */
public function addExploit($exploit)
{
        $this->exploits->add($exploit);

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @param Collection $exploits
 *
 * @return Author
 */
public function setExploits(Collection $exploits)
{
    $this->exploits->clear();

    foreach ($exploits as $exploit) {
        $exploit->add($this);
    }

    $this->exploits = $exploits;

    return $this;
}
}
::::::::::::::
Exploit.php
::::::::::::::
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use AppBundle\Entity\Author;
use AppBundle\Entity\Type;
use AppBundle\Entity\Category;

/**
 * Exploit
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="exploit", indexes={@ORM\Index(name=exploit_category_idx", columns={"category"}), @ORM\Index(name="exploit_type_idx", columns={"type"}), @ORM\Index(name="exploit_author_idx", columns={"
author"})})
 */
class Exploit
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="bigint", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="edb_id", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
     */
    private $edbId;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $date;

     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Author", inversedBy="exploits")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="author", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $author;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

     /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Category", inversedBy="exploits")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="version", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $version;

     /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Type", inversedBy="exploits")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="type", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text", nullable=false)
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="dork", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $dork;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="software_link", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $softwareLink;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="tested_on", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $testedOn;



    /**
     * Set edbId
     *
     * @param integer $edbId
     *
     * @return Exploit
     */
    public function setEdbId($edbId)
    {
        $this->edbId = $edbId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get edbId
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getEdbId()
    {
        return $this->edbId;
    }

    /**
     * Set date
     *
     * @param \DateTime $date
     *
     * @return Exploit
     */
    public function setDate($date)
    {
        $this->date = $date;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get date
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDate()
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    /**
     * Set author
     *
     * @param integer $author
     *
     * @return Exploit
     */
    public function setAuthor($author)
    {
        $this->author = $author;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get author
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getAuthor()
    {
        return $this->author;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Exploit
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set category
     *
     * @param integer $category
     *
     * @return Exploit
     */
    public function setCategory($category)
    {
        $this->category = $category;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get category
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    /**
     * Set version
     *
     * @param string $version
     *
     * @return Exploit
     */
    public function setVersion($version)
    {
        $this->version = $version;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get version
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getVersion()
    {
        return $this->version;
    }

    /**
     * Set type
     *
     * @param integer $type
     *
     * @return Exploit
     */
    public function setType($type)
    {
        $this->type = $type;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get type
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getType()
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    /**
     * Set content
     *
     * @param string $content
     *
     * @return Exploit
     */
    public function setContent($content)
    {
        $this->content = $content;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get content
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getContent()
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    /**
     * Set dork
     *
     * @param string $dork
     *
     * @return Exploit
     */
    public function setDork($dork)
    {
        $this->dork = $dork;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dork
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDork()
    {
        return $this->dork;
    }

    /**
     * Set softwareLink
     *
     * @param string $softwareLink
     *
     * @return Exploit
     */
    public function setSoftwareLink($softwareLink)
    {
        $this->softwareLink = $softwareLink;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get softwareLink
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSoftwareLink()
    {
        return $this->softwareLink;
    }

    /**
     * Set testedOn
     *
     * @param string $testedOn
     *
     * @return Exploit
     */
    public function setTestedOn($testedOn)
    {
        $this->testedOn = $testedOn;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get testedOn
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTestedOn()
    {
        return $this->testedOn;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
::::::::::::::
Type.php
::::::::::::::
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use AppBundle\Entity\Exploit;

/**
 * Type
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="type", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="type_name_id_idx", columns={"id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Type
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;


/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Exploit", mappedBy="type", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="exploits", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $exploits;

/**
 * Type constructor.
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->exploits = new ArrayCollection();
}

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Type
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function __toString() 
    {
        return $this->name;
    }


/**
 * @param Exploits $exploit
 *
 * @return Type
 */
public function addExploit($exploit)
{
        $this->exploits->add($exploit);

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @param Collection $exploits
 *
 * @return Type
 */
public function setExploits(Collection $exploits)
{
    $this->exploits->clear();

    foreach ($exploits as $exploit) {
        $exploit->add($this);
    }

    $this->exploits = $exploits;

    return $this;
}

}
```

but somehow when I make a query I get, like:

```
$exploits = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:Exploit')
            ->findAll();
```

and in view

```
<th scope="row"> {{ exploit.id }} </th> 
        <td> {{ exploit.name }} </td> 
        <td> {{ exploit.author.name }} </td>
        <td> {{ exploit.type.name }} </td>
        <td> {{ exploit.category.name }} </td>
        <td>{{ exploit.date|date('F j, Y, g:i a') }}</td>
```

I get this error:

```
Impossible to access an attribute ("name") on a integer variable ("1").
```

Any good soul can look into this and try to reproduce it?

MySQL Dump to recreate the tables with content is here:

https://0bin.net/paste/2tV3MEw4A2tdAVsR#R3rBNW4seWkK9HtlJFwbsA6+RmhhWPilm40L8QfeiTp

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It says it right there, you're trying to access the `name` attribute of something, but that something isn't an object. Its a `1`.

You access `.name` several times so unsure which one of these it is without more info and a line number

```
 <th scope="row"> {{ exploit.id }} </th> 
    <td> {{ exploit.name }} </td> 
    <td> {{ exploit.author.name }} </td>
    <td> {{ exploit.type.name }} </td>
    <td> {{ exploit.category.name }} </td>
    <td>{{ exploit.date|date('F j, Y, g:i a') }}</td>  
 </th>
```

But if we assume its `Author` then its clear that the `getAuthor()` method returns a `bigint`.

How did you get that entity code and the database code? Because they do not look correct, they are getting and setting integers, rather than objects.

**UPDATE**

Generate entities with

```
php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle
```

View the SQL using

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

Execute the SQL using

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Comment: Thanks!!! You got the point there. I did created DB by hand. At first I did create entities from database (2 Symfony commands) and than tuned it after reading tutorials and SO answers. How can I generate properly entities based on my DB scheme or how/what should I adjust for it to work with my current entities? BIG THANKS!

Comment: :/ Still the same ... Impossible to access an attribute ("name") on a integer variable ("1")

Comment: I populate DB with other Python script ... could this be the problem?

Comment: Delete your entities to make sure they are being created anew.`getAuthor` is returning an int see here `@return integer` but should be returning an `Author` object. As for python, no idea. Are you using Doctrine 2, MySQL and PDO?

Comment: I am using Symfony3. How do I change it to return an Author object?

Comment: Tried to change it to Author instead or integer

Comment: I think you need to go back to the docs and write your annotations correctly. References to other entities are not ints. Then generate your DB again.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with these entities:

```
::::::::::::::
Author.php
::::::::::::::
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use AppBundle\Entity\Exploit;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="author")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class Author
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="a_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $a_id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Exploit", mappedBy="author")
     */
    protected $exploits;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->exploits = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function addExploit(\AppBundle\Entity\Exploit $exploit)
    {
        $this->report[] = $exploit;
    }

    public function getExploits()
    {
        return $this->exploits;
    }
     /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Type
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

}

::::::::::::::
Category.php
::::::::::::::
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use AppBundle\Entity\Exploit;

/**
 * Category
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="category")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\CategoryRepository")
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="c_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $c_id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

/**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Exploit", mappedBy="category")
     */
    protected $exploits;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->exploits = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function addExploit(\AppBundle\Entity\Exploit $exploit)
    {
        $this->report[] = $exploit;
    }

    public function getExploits()
    {
        return $this->exploits;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Type
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

}

::::::::::::::
Exploit.php
::::::::::::::
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use AppBundle\Entity\Author;

/**
 * Exploit
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="exploit")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ReportRepository")
 */
class Exploit
{
   /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="e_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $e_id;

  /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Author", inversedBy="exploi
ts")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="author_id", referencedColumnName="a_id")
     */
    protected $author;

    public function setAuthor(\AppBundle\Entity\Author $author)
    {
        $this->author = $author;
    }

    public function getAuthor()
    {
        return $this->author;
    }

      /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Category", inversedBy="expl
oits")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="c_id")
     */
    protected $category;

    public function setCategory(\AppBundle\Entity\Category $category)
    {
        $this->category = $category;
    }

    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

      /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Type", inversedBy="exploits
")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="type_id", referencedColumnName="t_id")
     */
    protected $type;

    public function setType(\AppBundle\Entity\Type $type)
    {
        $this->type = $type;
    }

    public function getType()
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="edb_id", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
     */
    private $edbId;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $date;


    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;
  /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="version", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $version;
      /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text", nullable=false)
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="dork", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $dork;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="software_link", type="string", length=255, nullable=tru
e)
     */
    private $softwareLink;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="tested_on", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $testedOn;

     /**
     * Set edbId
     *
     * @param integer $edbId
     *
     * @return Exploit
     */
    public function setEdbId($edbId)
    {
        $this->edbId = $edbId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get edbId
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getEdbId()
    {
        return $this->edbId;
    }

    /**
     * Set date
     *
     * @param \DateTime $date
     *
     * @return Exploit
     */
    public function setDate($date)
    {
        $this->date = $date;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get date
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDate()
    {
        return $this->date;
    }
/**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Exploit
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
 /**
     * Set version
     *
     * @param string $version
     *
     * @return Exploit
     */
    public function setVersion($version)
    {
        $this->version = $version;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get version
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getVersion()
    {
        return $this->version;
    }
/**
     * Set content
     *
     * @param string $content
     *
     * @return Exploit
     */
    public function setContent($content)
    {
        $this->content = $content;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get content
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getContent()
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    /**
     * Set dork
     *
     * @param string $dork
     *
     * @return Exploit
     */
    public function setDork($dork)
    {
        $this->dork = $dork;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dork
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDork()
    {
        return $this->dork;
    }

    /**
     * Set softwareLink
     *
     * @param string $softwareLink
     *
     * @return Exploit
     */
    public function setSoftwareLink($softwareLink)
    {
        $this->softwareLink = $softwareLink;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get softwareLink
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSoftwareLink()
    {
        return $this->softwareLink;
    }

    /**
     * Set testedOn
     *
     * @param string $testedOn
     *
     * @return Exploit
     */
    public function setTestedOn($testedOn)
    {
        $this->testedOn = $testedOn;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get testedOn
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTestedOn()
    {
        return $this->testedOn;
    }

    /**
     * Get e_id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function gete_id()
    {
        return $this->e_id;
    }




}

::::::::::::::
Type.php
::::::::::::::
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use AppBundle\Entity\Exploit;

/**
 * Type
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="type")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\TypeRepository")
 */
class Type
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="t_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $t_id;

   /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;
/**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Exploit", mappedBy="type")
     */
    protected $exploits;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->exploits = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function addExploit(\AppBundle\Entity\Exploit $exploit)
    {
        $this->report[] = $exploit;
    }

    public function getExploits()
    {
        return $this->exploits;
    }


    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Type
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

}
```

This view:

```
 {% for exploit in exploits %}
            <tr> 
                <th scope="row">{{ exploit.e_id }}</th> 
                <td>{{ exploit.name }}</td> 
                <td> {{ exploit.author.name }} </td>
                <td> {{ exploit.category.name }} </td>
                <td> {{ exploit.type.name }} </td>

                <td>
                    <a href="/details/{{ exploit.e_id }}" class="btn btn-success">View</a>
                    <a href="/edit/{{ exploit.e_id }}" class="btn btn-default">Edit</a>
                    <a href="/delete/{{ exploit.e_id }}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                </td> 
            </tr> 
            {% endfor %}
```

And controller:

```
$exploits = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('AppBundle:Exploit')
    ->findAll();

return $this->render('exploit/index.html.twig', array(
    'exploits' => $exploits
));
```